# Why some strings are not inserted into PostgreSQL table from java?

Tags: java, string, postgresql, insert, pgadmin

What could be the reason that some strings are not inserted into PostgreSQL table from Java?

This happens after an update of source of data from API v1 to API v2. The inserted data structure is almost the same, float values are inserted, but some strings are not. And without any error: the fields are just empty.

It is probably some escape character but I'm not able to figure out which one. And how to fix it as well. The string length is about 6k characters and its PostgreSQL representation is text.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_data_string(in_ts bigint, in_ids integer[], in_string_values text[])
      RETURNS integer AS
    $BODY$
    DECLARE
      tmp_id integer;
      tmp_index integer;
    BEGIN
      tmp_index := 0;
      FOREACH tmp_id IN ARRAY in_ids LOOP
        tmp_index := tmp_index +1;
        INSERT INTO data (ts, id, string_value) VALUES (in_ts, tmp_id, in_string_values[tmp_index]);
      END LOOP;
      RETURN tmp_index;
    END;
```

The strings are passed into the procedure like this:

```
 cs.setArray(3, con.createArrayOf("varchar", (String[]) values));
```

There is one more thing: if the stored procedure is modified, for the sake of debug, that only first five characters of the string are inserted, e.g. like this:

```
INSERT INTO data (ts, id, string_value) VALUES (in_ts, tmp_id, substring(0, 5, in_string_values[tmp_index]));
```

the first five characters are inserted as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Check the in_ids and in_string_values arrays before you pass them to PostgreSQL. My guess is that their sizes do not match (the string_values array probably has a few extra empty string values you do not expect) like this

```
ids    string_values
1      "string that makes it to the database"
2      ""  //unexpected empty string
       "string which does not get inserted in the database"
```

Comment: It is a good guess but unfortunately it's not the case. There is just one string and just one id which means the sizes of arrays matches. And no string is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in pgAdmin III which for some strange reason does show empty fields for strings longer than 3640 characters even though the value Max. characters per column is set to 4096.